# Passing section of query result into session variables with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm having trouble passing the result of a query into a session variable, I think that the easiest way to do this is through Javascript. I have the query result showing but they will not pass to the session variable. At the end of each query resultant row, I have an add button that will activate the JS function to add to the session variable.

Query Result:

`echo '<tr><td>'.$products['Name'].'</td><td>£'.$products['Price'].'</td><td>'.$products['Category'].'</td><td><img src="'.$products['Image'].'" width=100px /></td><td>'.$products['ProductID'].'</td><td><button onclick="setProduct('.$products['ProductID'].')">Add to Basket</button></td></tr>';`

JS Function:

```
function setProduct(x){

var productID = x;
'<%Session["ProductID"] = "'+$products['productID']+'";%>';
```

Code displaying contents of session variable:

```
echo $_SESSION['ProductID'];
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't have access to session-variables...?

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION` is a server-side variable. You'd most likely want to set a `$_COOKIE` instead. Those are accessible on the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer posted, you can create a jQuery post request (or you can use AJAX) and send the JS session as value to a PHP file where you can access that value and create the corresponding PHP session.

Let's say, your JS function:

```
function setProduct(x){

    var productID = x;
    '<%Session["ProductID"] = "'+$products['productID']+'";%>';

    // ...

    $.post('example.php', { session_name: YOUR-SESSION-NAME, session_value: YOUR-SESSION-VALUE });
```

**example.php**:

```
if (isset($_POST['session_name']) && isset($_POST['session_value'])) {
    $_SESSION[$_POST['session_name']] = $_POST['session_value'];
}
```

**This is not taking into consideration security issues you might face**. You should encrypt your data before sending it.